# mysql_escape_string problem with image url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text-area where text and an image url is entered.

Text is formatted like this:

```
         my best friend's email is ............
         etc
         http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif
```

After the form is submitted, I use `mysql_escape_string()` to store the value in my database

My problem is image the url has changed.

How can I store this type of data in mysql using php with the correct (original, unaltered) image url?

-Thanks

Comment: What ends up in the database?

Comment: the url in the example should not change at all , only "friend's" will become "friend\'s" .. put up an example which is actually causing you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead, that one you're using is deprecated and its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are double escaping the string.

Eg PHP with magic quotes on will escape the values in POST and GET before your script begins executing and if you then call mysql_escape_string as well..., well, it would be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise splitting your textarea into a textarea and a text input field for the image url. Different containers for different things.

You can debug this problem by echo'ing the pre-escaped, post-escaped strings and the SQL query that put's it in the database.